# Of the 4 properties (transitivity, anti-symmetry, symmetry, and reflexivity) that a relation could hold, which two are not possible?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

There are sixteen combinations of these four properties on relations, and I believe one of the impossible combinations is Reflexive, Symmetric, Not Anti-symmetric, and Not transitive. However, I am having trouble finding contradictions in the other fifteen combinations.

Comment: See [Transitive relation : properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation#Properties) : "A transitive relation is asymmetric if and only if it is irreflexive." And see [Relationship to asymmetric and antisymmetric relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_relation#Relationship_to_asymmetric_and_antisymmetric_relations).

Answer (score 1):

** Wrong answer (sorry) **
The relation $R = \emptyset$ on the set $\emptyset$ has all 16 configurations of those properties. So none of them are contradictory.

Comment: $R=\emptyset$ is always antisymmetrc and always transitive and always symmetric. Whether it is reflexive or not depends on the base set.

Comment: Assuming the base set is $\emptyset$ it's going to be ok i think.

Comment: If the base set is $\emptyset$, then $R=\emptyset$ is reflexive, antisymmetric, symmetric, and transitive

Comment: It is also not reflexive, not ... aswell.

Comment: How is it not tra? Show me $x,y,z$ with $xRy$, $yRz$, and not $x Rz$

Comment: Firstly i apologize for "not tra". I accidentally submitted it too early. Since you assume that x, y, z exist in the universe of this model you can derive anything because it's empty. I am actually not really familiar with models that have an empty universe but i guess if we were allowed to construct such models then any sentence would be true in them. Including the always false sentence.

Comment: With an empty model, any sentece that starts with $\exists$ (such as the negation of a sentence that starts with $\forall$ and therefore is vacuously true) is false. Reflexivity etc. *are* sentences that start with $\forall$.

Comment: Ahh, you're right. Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 1):

Here are (minimal?) example sets and relations for all fourteen possible combinations of the properties; the zeroes and ones are a short for whether (in this order) reflexivity, symmetry, anti-symmetry, transitivity hold.

0000: $X=\{1,2,3\}$,  $R=\{(1,2), (2,3), (3,2)\}$

0001: $X=\{1,2,3\}$,  $R=\{(1,2), (2,3), (3,2), (1,3), (2,2), (3,3)\}$

0010: $X=\{1,2,3\}$,  $R = \{ (1,2), (2,3) \}$

0011: $X=\{1,2\}$,  $R = \{ (1,2) \}$

0100: $X=\{1,2\}$, $R = \{ (1,2), (2,1) \}$

0101: $X=\{1,2,3\}$, $R = \{ (1,2), (2,1), (1,1), (2,2) \}$

0110: Impossible because symmetry and antisymmetry imply transitivity: Assume $aRb$ and $bRc$. Then $cRb$ by symmetry. Then $b=c$ by anti-symmetry and hence  $aRc$.

0111: $X=\{1\}$, $R=\emptyset$

1000: $X=\{1,2,3\}$, $R = \{ (1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (1,2), (2,3), (2,1) \}$

1001: $X=\{1,2,3\}$, $R = \{ (1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (1,2), (2,3), (3,2), (1,3) \}$

1010:  $X=\{1,2,3\}$, $R = \{ (1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (1,2), (2,3) \}$

1011: $X=\{1,2\}$, $R = \{ (1,1),(2,2), (1,2) \}$

1100:  $X=\{1,2,3\}$, $R = \{ (1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (1,2), (2,1), (2,3), (3,2) \}$

1101: $X=\{1,2\}$, $R = \{ (1,1), (2,2), (1,2), (2,1) \}$

1110: Impossible, see 0110

1111: $X=R=\emptyset$